# Dynamically inserting multiple rows to a table

Tags: sql

I need to insert multiple records into a table. The number of records depend on the result of another query. For example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(colm1, colm2, colm3)
VALUES(SELECT clom1 FROM TABLE2, constant, constant)
```

In this query `colm2`, `colm3` have constsnt values, the value of `colm1` differs based on the ouput of `TABLE2`, and the number of records that are to be inserted also depend upon the number of values from `TABLE2`. Can someone give me a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table1(colm1,colm2,colm3)
SELECT colm1,constant,constant FROM TABLE2
```

This should work

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(colm1, colm2, colm3) 
SELECT clom1, constant, constant FROM TABLE2
. . .
```